# marginals of Dirichlet distribution (using Gamma definition)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let be $X=(X_1,\cdots,X_k)\sim \operatorname{Dirichlet}(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_k).$ Find the distribution of any marginal vector $(X_r,\cdots,X_h)$, $1\leq r\leq h\leq k.$

I found the following definition of Dirichlet distribution:

Let  $X=(\frac{Y_1}{\sum_{i=1}^kY_i},\cdots,\frac{Y_k}{\sum_{i=1}^kY_i});$ $Y_i\sim \Gamma (\alpha _i,1)$. Then $X\sim \operatorname{Dirichlet}(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_k).$

Can I use this definition to find the marginal distributions? 
There is other easier method to find the distributions or marginals?

Comment: The marginal distribution of the $X_i$ are Beta$(\alpha_i, \alpha_0 -\alpha_i)$ with $\alpha_0 = \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i$ (individually)

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/317941/showing-z-is-are-independent-if-z-1-sum-i-1n1x-i-and-z-i-fracx-i.